# ¿Cómo usar la variable var e asignar otra en un switch en JAVA?

Tags: java

Tengo en el siguiente ejemplo donde tengo que desarrollar un programa que asigne un valor a la variable cuarto, tengo conocimientos básicos de programación y, lo visto no me parece correcto:

La cuestión es que al usar el siguiente ejemplo de inicio, me sale error todo tanto `var mes = "Enero"` como `var cuarto = switch ( mes )` lo que impide agregar las condiciones donde se me solicita aquí `//Su código debe ir aquí`

```
var mes = "Enero"
var cuarto = switch ( mes ) {
   //Su código debe ir aquí
}
```

A diferencia de este ejemplo donde declaro las variables y logro imprimir:

```
    char cuarto;
    
    cuarto = 'b';
    
    switch(cuarto){
        case 'a':
        case 'b': {
            System.out.println("Texto...");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'switch' no regresa ningún valor.

Comment: @JoséMaría en mi segundo ejemplo si, pero el primer ejemplo es que no se como utilizarlo porque al usar tal cual `var` muestra error

Comment: La verdad que no hay mucho de donde entender lo que quieres hacer, en ambos cosas se hacen cosas muy distintas, de todas formas, como dice un comentario mas arriba, SWITCH no retorna valores, no puedes asignar nada de esa forma. Explica un poco mejor por favor.

Comment: @JavierSnachez Amigo en conclusión, tengo que hacer ejecutar el primer ejemplo. Preguntada editada.

Comment: Pero es lo que te explicamos, SWITCH no es una funcion, no retorna resultados, por lo que no se puede hacer variable = switch(var) {... porque SWITCH es como hacer varios IF ELSE, podria ser algo asi en todo caso; var mes = "Enero";
var cuarto = "";
switch ( mes ) {
   case "Enero" {cuarto = "e"; break; /* por ejemplo */}
}

Comment: Además, en Java, no se utiliza la variable 'var' para las variables. Se coloca primero su tipo y luego su nombre. El primer ejemplo más parece de Javascript.

Comment: @JoséMaría me temo que `var` es una palabra válida en java a partir de la versión 10, ojo, no significa que no sea tipado, simplemente al declarar `var` se infiere el tipo de la variable, es simplemente una manera más breve de escribir algunos tipos (por ejemplo si estás usando una caché de listas de objetos de tipo X, se quedaría muy largo de escribir, mientras que `var cache;` es más corto y se entiende igual si sabes de que va el código. [Aquí](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-var-keyword-y-su-uso-con-jdk10/) se puede leer algo al respecto con algunas ejemplos.

Comment: @JoséMaría Yo también pensaba que `var` era en `javascript` pero si lo emplea `Java`

Comment: @Benito-B Pero porque `var cuarto = switch ( mes )` esto? No entiendo...

Comment: @Valentina eso no tiene sentido, tal como dijeron muchos antes, switch no es una función que devuelva algo, no puede usarse así en las actuales versiones de java.